# Реализация java

Tags: java

Как мне реализовать на JAVA и возможно ли это применительно к массиву. "Если сразу **все** элементы массива принимают значения **true** то ..."
для динамического  массива

```
     ArrayList<Boolean> ArrCheckDH = new ArrayList<>();
               for (int i=0; i<EditPerDayTrue.size(); i++) {
                EdTxt1(EditPerDayTrue.get(i));
                EdTxt1(EditPerHourTrue.get(i));
                ArrCheckDH = new ArrayList<>();
                // Заполняем массив значениями true или false
                ArrCheckDH.add(EdTxt1(EditPerDayTrue.get(i)));

                Log.d(TAG, "Name "+ ArrCheckDH);
            }
            if (ArrCheck(ArrCheckDH)) {
                calc_button.setEnabled(true);
            } else {
                calc_button.setEnabled(false);
            }

     // создание метода для проверки всех значений массива на TRUE
        static boolean ArrCheck (ArrayList<Boolean> ArrCheck) {
           for (boolean b : ArrCheck) {
          if (!b) {
            return false;
          }
         }
           return true;
           }
```

Comment: не очень понятен вопрос, добавьте конкретики

Comment: А в чём проблема? Одна строка кода, это всё, что у вас получилось?

Comment: Есть массив данных их количество неизвестно (но больше 2-х) я хочу проверить если сразу все значения true то выполняется какое-нибудь действие. Возможна такая реализация применительно к массиву или надо искать что-то другое.. Мне не хочется раздувать код и задавать явную проверку каждого значения.

Answer (score 4):

На Java 7 простым циклом

```
boolean flag = true;
for (boolean value : arr) {
    if (!value)
        flag = false;
    }
}
if(flag) {
    //Какие-то действия
}
```

На Java 8 можно через Stream API

```
if(IntStream.range(0, arr.length).allMatch(i -> arr[i])){
    //Какие-то действия
}
```

Или

```
collection.stream().allMatch((s) -> s)
```

Answer (score 3):

На [kotlin](/questions/tagged/kotlin) можно, например, [так](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1097770/%d0%a0%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-java/1097779#comment1891137_1097779):

```
val isAllTrue = someArrayListWithBooleans.all { it }
```

Или так, что менее красиво:

```
val isAllTrue = someArrayListWithBooleans.filter { it }.size() == someArrayListWithBooleans.size()
```

Comment: Можно ещё так: `someArrayListWithBooleans.all { it }`

Comment: @Ziens, действительно)